# jsonapi-serializer hide the id of a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jsonapi-serializer

Using [jsonapi-serializer](https://github.com/jsonapi-serializer/jsonapi-serializer) I don't want to return the ID of the blog post, eventually I'll return a custom slug instead, but I cant figure out how to remove fields in the serializer.

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": "6",
        "type": "blog_post",
        "attributes": {
            "email": "mark@example.com",
            "name": "Mark"
        }
    }
}
```

I tried using a conditional proc to hide the id to no avail:

```
class BlogPostSerializer
  include JSONAPI::Serializer
  attributes :email, :name
  attribute :id, if: Proc.new { false }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah it turns out you need an ID per the JSON API spec:
[https://discuss.jsonapi.org](https://discuss.jsonapi.org/t/clarification-on-ids-in-attributes/967/8)

I didn't want to reveal the actual `id` of the blog post however, so you can tell the serializer to return the uuid instead:

```
set_id :uuid
attributes :email, :name, :uuid
```